# iText7 setRotation() not working properly

Tags: java, pdf, itext, itext7

I'm making a small Java program that can modify an existing PDF, and save the changes in a new PDF, using iTextPDF 7. I started with a rotating feature, using `setRotation()` on a `PdfDocument`, but my PDF output is rotating 90 degree less than the value I put as a parameter.

So `setRotation(90)` makes no changes,
`setRotation(180)` does a single clockwise change,
`setRotation(270)` does a double turn (180 degree rotation).
etc..

Here's my Code:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;

public class rotateMyPDF {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  {

        PdfReader in_pdf = new PdfReader("in.pdf");
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(in_pdf, new PdfWriter("out.pdf"));

        for (int i=1; i<=pdfDoc.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
            pdfDoc.getPage(i).setRotation(270);  //error here?

        }
        pdfDoc.close();
        System.out.println("done.");
    }
}
```

Seems like a bug? Or is there an error in my code? Or is this intended functionality?
If I put `setRotation(0)`, the PDF pages are rotated 90 degrees counter clockwise!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to misunderstand the `setRotation` method. It does not *add* to the current rotation but it *sets* the rotation value.

Thus, if your page already had page rotation applied, setting the same value with `setRotation` will change nothing etc.

Your source page appears to already be rotated by 90°. That would explain the observation:

> So `setRotation(90)` makes no changes,
>   `setRotation(180)` does a single clockwise change,
>   `setRotation(270)` does a double turn (180 degree rotation).
>   etc..

Simply first read the current rotation value with `getRotation`, add the desired extra rotation, and then set that sum using `setRotation`.

Comment: Ah, thank you! That makes a lot of sense, I'm just new to iText.